# Difference between using HTTP GET request on URL vs Local .html file?

Tags: java, http, get

Can someone please help explain to me the differences between the two? The URL instance seems simple enough to me, but I am having trouble doing the same thing with a local file.

Comment: Please add some context. You don't make an HTTP GET request to a local file. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Basically I want to access a .html file through a local webserver using a GET method. I want to be able to display the file in my browser.

Comment: Then send the request to `localhost`.

Comment: Also, a web server does not serve files. It receives HTTP requests, handles them, and returns an HTTP response. The HTTP response may or may not have been generated by copying bytes from a file on the server, but that information is hidden from you.

Comment: So, after sending the HTTP request through my server, I should be returning the files contents through a PrintWriter back to the client?

Comment: That's one way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing a file directly, chrome is repsonsible for accessing the file on disk and rendering it.  When using a server, the server reads the file from disk and sends it over http, and *then* chrome renders it.

You may need to make sure you allow Chrome access to the local files.  Add the `--allow-file-access-from-files` switch to your shortcut that starts chrome.

Otherwise, you will get errors when your HTML file tries to access other resources on disk.

See http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/

---

**Update**

For Firefox, you want to go to:

`about:config`

And change the flag for `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` to FALSE.

Comment: I am using firefox, from what I understand that issue is only on Chrome right?

Comment: @Friar Bob - Nope.  Firefox has the same policy, but you have to change it differently.  See update in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should run HTTP server on your machine and make calls to `http://localhost/`